# Create 2 objects in array on document create in Mongoose model

Tags: mongoose, schema

Bit of a strange question, but I have an Mongoose schema with an array of object i.e.

```
:
evaluations: [{
    internetAddress: {type: String, default: ''},
    name: String,
    submitted: {type: Boolean,default: false}
]
```

When I create a new document using

`await Mode.create({})`

how do I create two objects in that evaluations array?

I was hoping one of these three options:

1. In the model create method, or
2. In a pre 'create' hook, if one exists, or
3. As a default in the model schema

but can't seem to get any of these to work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the create method,  just pass an array to the evaluations field like this: `[{internetAddress: "addr1", name: "name1", submitted: false},
 {internetAddress: "addr2", name: "name2", submitted: false}]`

Comment: @SuleymanSah Thanks. Using `evaluator: [{internetAddress="addr1"},{internetAddress="addrs2"}]` worked